# Using reverse proxy for http and https mixed content

Tags: http, iframe, https, proxy, varnish

We're working on a web application which allows the user to do some design for mobile devices.  The user simply enters some url and that url is previewed inside some iframe. The problem is, our application is running on https and if the user enters a non-https address it's not displayed by the browser for obvious reasons...

So can we use some reverse-proxy configuration to overcome this issue somehow? For example we'll  set the iframe url as http://myserver.com/?url=http://externalserver.com and the reverse proxy will simply return the externalserver.com content back...

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Did you manage to advance in your problem? did you manage to try it out?

Comment: Nope... It looks like NginX can do it by using some variables but couldn't find the time to test it yet...